# Passing complex model to controller with .net core 3 mvc

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had this issue before and fixed it with replacing foreach loop with For loop.
But with .net core 3, this doesn't work anymore. The child object inside the parent object returns null.

Basically i am developing a employee training booking system for selected staff. 
I have got a employeeList with select checkbox. And TraineeList to save selected employee from Employee list

```
public class TraineeListVM
{
    public List<TraineeListModel> TraineeList { get; set; }
    public List<BookingEmpVM> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    public BookingModel BookingModel { get; set; }
}

public class BookingEmpVM
{
    public EmployeeModel EmployeeModel { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrainingExpData { get; set; }
    public bool EmpSelected { get; set; } = false;
}
```

To Populate data

```
        public IActionResult Index(int bookingID)
    {
        List<TraineeListModel> Tlist = traineeListRepository.TraineeLists.Where(b => b.BookingID == bookingID).ToList();
        List<EmployeeModel> EmpList = employeeRepository.EmployeeList.Where(e => e.EmployeeStatus == true).ToList();
        List<BookingEmpVM> EmpListWithExpDate = new List<BookingEmpVM>();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var emp in EmpList)
        {
            i++;
            EmpListWithExpDate.Add(new BookingEmpVM
            {
                EmployeeModel = new EmployeeModel
                {
                    EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,
                    Name = emp.FullName,
                    ProjectModel = emp.ProjectModel
                },
                EmpSelected = false,
                TrainingExpData = DateTime.Now
            });

            if (i == 30) break;
        }
        return View(new TraineeListVM
        {
            TraineeList = Tlist,
            EmployeeList = EmpListWithExpDate,
            BookingModel = bookingRepository.BookingList.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BookingID == bookingID)
        });
    }
```

in cshtml

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeList.Count(); i++)
 {
     <tr>
        <td>
             @Model.EmployeeList[i].EmployeeModel.EmployeeID
        </td>
        <td>
             @Model.EmployeeList[i].EmployeeModel.FullName
        </td>
        <td>                                                    
             @Model.EmployeeList[i].EmployeeModel.ProjectModel.ProjectName
        </td>
        <td>
              @Model.EmployeeList[i].TrainingExpData.ToShortDateString()
        </td>
        <td>
               <input asp-for="@Model.EmployeeList[i].EmpSelected" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
```

Number of returned EmployeeList iscorrect but EmployeeModel inside the EmployeeList is null.
[image]

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: How do you fill the Parent and child Objects?

Comment: Code in the view seems ok, I think you should check how you populate the model.

Comment: Data comes from  SQL table via EF, i used ApplicationDbContext,

Comment: Can you share the function you use to fill the data model? the problem should be over there not in your models.

Comment: Hi Ali, I add codes taht shows how i populate data models before pass it to View

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this code is producing the problem? As far as I can see, `EmpSelected` should always be false, but it is true in your case, which is not even the normal "default" value.

Comment: Hi Grek! You are right I set all  EmpSelected = false before i send to View,  but on the web page I tick a few of these checkboxes and click submit button. This is why the one i selected comes true and unchecked false. But why EmployeeID and others returns empty. The only difference is empSelected is attribute and EmployeModel is an object.